# Python write bytes to file using redirect of print

Tags: python, linux

using perl,

```
$ perl -e 'print "\xca"' > out
```

now `$ xxd out`

we have

```
00000000: ca
```

But with Python, I tried

```
$ python3 -c 'print("\xca", end="")' > out
$ xxd out
```

what I got is

```
00000000: c38a
```

I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Strings are unicode in Python encoded as UTF-8 by default. Try `import sys; sys.stdout.write(b'\xca')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in Python, a `str` object is a series of unicode code points. How this is *printed to the screen* depends on the encoding of your `sys.stdout`. This is picked based on your locale (or possibly various environment variables can affect this, but by default, it is your locale). So yours must be set to UTF-8. That's my default too:

```bash
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ python -c "print('\xca', end='')" | xxd
00000000: c38a
```

However, if I override my locale and tell it to use `en_US.ISO8859-1` (latin-1), a single-byte encoding, we get what you expect:

```bash
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ LC_ALL="en_US.ISO8859-1" python -c "print('\xca', end='')" | xxd
00000000: ca
```

The solution is to work with raw bytes if you want raw bytes. The way to do that in Python source code is to use a bytes literal (or a string literal and then `.encode` it). We can use the raw buffer at `sys.stdout.buffer`:

```bash
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xca')" | xxd
00000000: ca
```

Or by encoding a string to a bytes object:

```
(py311) Juans-MBP:~ juan$ python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write('\xca'.encode('latin'))" | xxd
00000000: ca
```

Answer (score 1):

> **In python** \xca is interpreted as a **two-byte string** in the UTF-8
> encoding and that's why when a value is written inside a file it
> automatically stored two bytes in the file as `c3 8a`
>
> **But in perl** \xca is interpreted as a **single byte** with the hexadecimal
> value 0xca and for that when the value is stored inside the file it will save
> without encoding.

[You can check more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174463/difference-in-python-and-perl-print-regarding-character-encoding)